# Class Design - Load list in the class or can it be done in any other way?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently designing a class "User"

```
public class User
{
  ...
  public int LocationId {get; set;}
  public string LocationName 
  {
    get
    {
       //Get name from the LocationList based on the LocationId
    }
  }
  public List<SelectListItem> LocationList 
  {
    get
    {
       //Retrieve the location as list from DB
    }
  }
  ....
}
```

My concern is that each time a new object is created, the DB will be accessed and the location list will be retrieved.

Can a class be created this way? Or is there a better way of doing it? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `LocationName` and `LocationList` are not accessed every time you create a new `User` (unless, of course, you do `get` them in the constructor). As properties, they are accessed only when you reference them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database would only be hit when `LocationList` was accessed, not when the class is newed up. However, no, this is not the best way. Entity classes / view models should not interact with your context directly. The biggest reason for this is that you should really only have one and only one instance of your context and it's not always possible to properly inject it into these classes.

Instead, you should use a repository or service class to abstract away the query and then simply set the list property directly in your controller action by calling some method on your repository or service.

Answer (score 2):

There is one point in addition to what Chris mentioned, take a look on this rule:

[CA1002: Do not expose generic lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CA1002);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true).

So in general, the class shouldn't expose any property returning a generic list. Try to use one of these:

> System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection
>
> System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection
>
> System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always a good idea to make a repository whenever an external system/source should be communicated with.

In that way you have all logic that interacts with a given source in one place and can debug and edit it in that one specific place. Plus you should only have a single database context in use at any given time anyway as Chris Pratt mentions.